# Improve use of processor during training of ML model

Tags: python, cpu-architecture, hardware, processor, hardware-acceleration

I am using a new pc with intel i5 11th generation processor for machine learning. 
Usually when I train a model, I open the default 'task manager' by windows to check how processor and memory are used like in the picture.

[image]

as you can see here 30% of processor power is used(between 25% and 30% in all training phase). 
But in my older pc with processor inter i7 6th generation, the 30% used to be at least 80% when training. 
The models I train take at least few minutes to train, so it is not a running time of few seconds. 
I am totally not into hardware. I Hope someone is able to explain why that difference occurs. And if it is healthy to have 30% or 80% of processor power used during training.

Comment: With Python, I always thought this had something to do with the OS scheduling. I usually fix this by spawning more threads and then I'll get close to 100% CPU usage.

Comment: Does your new processor have more cores than your old one?

Answer (score 0):

You are limited by something else than the CPU (common would be GPU or RAM). The same 80% you saw on your old CPU just stresses the new one less because its more powerful.

Healthy has nothing to do with load, what could be unhealthy are CPU temperatures, you should aim to have them below 80°C, if they are higher youd do good in investing into a better cooler.